# how to use 'dry-run' in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm just a starter, dry-run is pretty useful to make a parameter to test, can any body tell me how to use it with an easy way? I googled that but few results on its uses.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 33):

### Use on existing cmdlets

Explicitly supply the -WhatIf parameter:

```
rm foo.txt -WhatIf
```

Result:

```
What if: Performing operation "Remove File" on Target "C:\temp\foo.txt".
```

### Use on existing cmdlets within a function or script

`SupportsShouldProcess` attribute automatically propagates `-WhatIf` to supported cmdlets:

```
function do-stuff
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    param([string]$file)
    Remove-Item $file
}

do-stuff foo.txt -WhatIf
```

Result:

```
What if: Performing operation "Remove File" on Target "C:\temp\foo.txt".
```

### Use on your own code blocks

Explicitly use `ShouldProcess()` method to determine whether `-WhatIf` was passed:

```
function do-stuff
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    param([string]$file)
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($file)) {
        Write-Host "Deleting file"
        Remove-Item $file
    }
}

do-stuff foo.txt -WhatIf
```

Result:

```
What if: Performing operation "do-stuff" on Target "foo.txt".
```

### Use on Nested functions in the *same* module

`SupportsShouldProcess` attribute automatically propagates `-WhatIf` to nested functions:

```
function do-stuff
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    param([string]$file)
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($file)) {
        Write-Host "Deleting file"
        Remove-Item $file
    }
    inner "text"
}

function inner
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    param([string]$s)
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($s)) {
        Write-Host "Inner task"
    }
    $s | out-file "temp9.txt"
}
do-stuff foo.txt -WhatIf
```

Result:

```
What if: Performing operation "do-stuff" on Target "foo.txt".
What if: Performing operation "inner" on Target "text".
What if: Performing operation "Output to File" on Target "temp9.txt".
```

### Use on Nested functions in a *different* module

Unfortunately, -WhatIf does not propagate automatically to functions defined in a different module. See [Powershell: How to get -whatif to propagate to cmdlets in another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984876/powershell-how-to-get-whatif-to-propagate-to-cmdlets-in-another-module) for discussion and workaround for this.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably referring to the `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm` parameters on cmdlets. You can read up about them in `Get-Help about_commonParameters`:

> **Risk Management Parameter Descriptions**
>
> ```
> -WhatIf[:{$true | $false}]
> ```
>
> > Displays a message that describes the effect of the command,
> >     instead of executing the command.
> >
> > WhatIf parameter overrides the value of the `$WhatIfPreference`
> >     variable for the current command. Because the default value of the
> >     `$WhatIfPreference` variable is `0` (disabled), WhatIf behavior is not
> >     performed without the WhatIf parameter. For more information, type
> >     the following command:
> >
> > ```
> > get-help about_preference_variables
> > ```
> >
> > *Valid values:*
> >
> > `$true` (`-WhatIf:$true`). Has the same effect as `-WhatIf`.
> >     `$false` (`-WhatIf:$false`). Suppresses the automatic WhatIf behavior
> >                 that results when the value of the $WhatIfPreference variable
> >                 is 1.
> >
> > For example, the following command uses the `WhatIf` parameter in a
> >             `Remove-Item` command:
> >
> > ```
> > PS> remove-item date.csv -whatif
> > ```
> >
> > Instead of removing the item, Windows PowerShell lists the operations
> >             it would perform and the items that would be affected. This command
> >             produces the following output:
> >
> > ```
> > What if: Performing operation "Remove File" on
> > Target "C:\ps-test\date.csv".
> > ```
>
> ```
> -Confirm[:{$true | $false}]
> ```
>
> > Prompts you for confirmation before executing the command.
> >
> > The Confirm parameter overrides the value of the $ConfirmPreference
> >             variable for the current command. The default value is High. For more
> >             information, type the following command:
> >
> > ```
> > get-help about_preference_variables
> > ```
> >
> > *Valid values:*
> >
> > `$true` (`-WhatIf:$true`). Has the same effect as `-Confirm`.
> >     `$false` (`-Confirm:$false`). Suppresses automatic confirmation,
> >                 which occurs when the value of `$ConfirmPreference` is less than
> >                 or equal to the estimated risk of the cmdlet.
> >
> > For example, the following command uses the Confirm parameter with a
> >             Remove-Item command. Before removing the item, Windows PowerShell
> >             lists the operations it would perform and the items that would be
> >             affected, and asks for approval.
> >
> > ```
> > PS C:\ps-test> remove-item tmp*.txt -confirm
> > ```
> >
> > This command produces the following output:
> >
> > ```
> > Confirm
> > Are you sure you want to perform this action?
> > Performing operation "Remove File" on Target " C:\ps-test\tmp1.txt
> > [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend
> > [?] Help (default is "Y"):
> > ```

Comment: thank you! so if I understood you right, all I need is add an param called $whatif and value it depend on change, so the console will not operate until $whatif -eq $true  am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is actually the module Pester (delivered with Windows 10 since first release) that can perform mock ups. I.e. pretend to run parts of the code for doing real isolated Unit test.

This is a big subject though...

[MS Scripting - What is Pester and Why Should I Care?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/what-is-pester-and-why-should-i-care/)