# how to make a dry run powershell script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a text.psl and wanna dry run that, what else do I need to write? it needs additional arrguments in file? Or what kind of parameters I need to create?.

I create a $WhatIf, but it didn't work...

Comment: How are you implementing your whatif parameter... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180271/how-do-you-support-powershells-whatif-confirm-parameters-in-a-cmdlet-that-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use 'dry-run' in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211518/how-to-use-dry-run-in-powershell)