# Powershell - how to combine -whatif with a -confirm?

Tags: powershell

I referenced this question: [how to use 'dry-run' in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211518/how-to-use-dry-run-in-powershell/11211801?s=1|0.1466#11211801) in my search and I get what it is saying already.

My question though is:

Can I have a Powershell script that invokes a -whatif, then comes back with a confirmation prompt to run the real command(s)?

An example:

```
#Disable Exchange access
set-casmailbox $1.samaccountname -ewsallowentourage $false -ecpenabled $false -ewsallowoutlook $false -ewsallowmacoutlook $false -activesyncenabled $false -owaenabled $false -OWAforDevicesEnabled $false -mapihttpenabled $false -ewsenabled $false -mapienabled $false
```

I would like the above to include a -WhatIf and then a prompt to confirm whether to run the real command(s) or not.

I figure I can do it somewhat sloppily by using:

```
#Check what happens if I disable Exchange Access
set-casmailbox $1.samaccountname -ewsallowentourage $false -ecpenabled $false -ewsallowoutlook $false -ewsallowmacoutlook $false -activesyncenabled $false -owaenabled $false -OWAforDevicesEnabled $false -mapihttpenabled $false -ewsenabled $false -mapienabled $false -whatif
#Prompt for Confirmation to actually disable Exchange Access
set-casmailbox $1.samaccountname -ewsallowentourage $false -ecpenabled $false -ewsallowoutlook $false -ewsallowmacoutlook $false -activesyncenabled $false -owaenabled $false -OWAforDevicesEnabled $false -mapihttpenabled $false -ewsenabled $false -mapienabled $false -confirm
```

But I was curious if there's a better way, especially since the above is a simple single line command versus a foreach,etc.

Answer (score 2):

This would have to be implemented in the cmdlet you are calling. You could sort of hack this together with your own function:

```
function Invoke-WhatIfThenConfirm {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [ScriptBlock]
    $ScriptBlock ,

    [Switch]
    $Force
)

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('Calling scriptblock')) {
        $prefSave = $WhatIfPreference
        try {
            $WhatIfPreference = 'Stop'
            & $ScriptBlock
        } finally {
            $WhatIfPreference = $prefSave
        }
        $confSave = $ConfirmPreference
        try {
            $ConfirmPreference = if ($Force) {
                'None'
            } else {
                'High'
            }
            & $ScriptBlock
        } finally {
            $ConfirmPreference = $confSave
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
Invoke-WhatIfThenConfirm -ScriptBlock {
    set-casmailbox $1.samaccountname -ewsallowentourage $false -ecpenabled $false -ewsallowoutlook $false -ewsallowmacoutlook $false -activesyncenabled $false -owaenabled $false -OWAforDevicesEnabled $false -mapihttpenabled $false -ewsenabled $false -mapienabled $false
}
```

If you use `-Force` it should force no confirmation.

This whole thing was just typed here though and I haven't tested it at all, so I'm not certain it will work, but it might be a good starting point.

---

## Alternative

You can use splatting to put your params in a hashtable and modify the switches:

```
$params = @{
    Identity = $1.samaccountname 
    ewsallowentourage = $false 
    ecpenabled = $false 
    ewsallowoutlook = $false 
    ewsallowmacoutlook = $false 
    activesyncenabled = $false 
    owaenabled = $false 
    OWAforDevicesEnabled = $false 
    mapihttpenabled = $false 
    ewsenabled = $false 
    mapienabled = $false
}

set-casmailbox @params -WhatIf
set-casmailbox @params -Confirm
```

---

The second option is a bit easier and probably less error prone, but works best for a call here or there to a single cmdlet where most parameters don't change.

The first option is more versatile for working with many different cmdlets and calling them more naturally.